# Ajustar ancho de la tabla bootstrap table

Tags: bootstrap, css3, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-table

Hola Estoy intentando que el contenido de la tabla me salga corrido en las columnas sin que se me desplace hacia abajo y me haga la fila muy ancha
en la imagen se puede ver como la columna Program no cabe el çontenido, la idea es poder agrandar mas la columna program pero no se si es cosa de bootstrap 
que no me deja, estoy usando para la tabla bootstrap-table en esta aplicacion .NET MVC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con la propiedad data-width = 45 pero no he tenido resultados

Ya esta resuelta con esta clase css

```
.clase{
 white-space: nowrap;
            overflow-x: auto;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de formar tu HTML podrías hacer esto.

```
<table id="productSizes" class="table">
<thead>
    <tr class="d-flex">
        <th class="col-1">Columna 1</th>
        <th class="col-3">Columna 2</th>
        <th class="col-5">Columna 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="d-flex">
        <td class="col-1">6</td>
        <td class="col-3">79 - 81</td>
        <td class="col-5">61 - 63</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

A la fila le ponemos la clase d-flex y las columnas col-n. Donde n representaría en ancho de la tabla, en este caso la columna "Program" seria por ejemplo col-6, solo debes probar.

Comment: hola gracias por tu respuesta, no me funciono tampoco asi, al parecer una clase arriba me limitaba a cambiar el tamaño, resolvi con esto  white-space: nowrap;
            overflow-x: auto;

Answer (score 0):

[Como indica Raidel Fonseca en su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/313140/ajustar-ancho-de-la-tabla-bootstrap-table/530680#comment568892_313156), se puede resolver agregando el CSS directamente en el HTML (uso bootstrap):

```
<table class="table" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: auto;">
```